# In MongoDB how to find documents where property is object but not Array

Tags: mongodb

I have collection `users` where each contains property `gyms` e.g.:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaaaa"),
    "firstName" : "first",
    "lastName" : "second",
    "email" : "aaa@aaaa",
    "password" : "aaaaa",
    "gyms" : [
        {
            "name" : "aaaaaa",
            "address" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I run `db.users.aggregate(..)` I get:

```
exception: Value at end of $unwind field path '$gyms' must be an Array, but is a Object
```

It seems that some of the users documents contain gym:{} or no gym at all rather than array. I need to find these documents, how would I do that?

EDIT:

Aggregate command I run:

```
db.users.aggregate({ $unwind: "$gyms" }, { $match: { "gyms.address": { $exists: true } } } )
```

Comment: Can you show us the full aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Something like this? https://gist.github.com/harrydenley/0fcecec1336cc738ce85

Comment: there should be an empty "gyms" :{  }

Answer (score 4):

Using `{$type: "object"}` gives you results containing documents with arrays too. So, to check for pure objects, just add an extra check to ensure that arrays are discarded, viz., `obj.0.key: {$exists: false}`.

In your case,

```
db.users.find({"gyms": {$type: "object"}, "gyms.0.name": {$exists: false}}).map(function(u) {
    // modify u.gyms to your satisfaction
    db.conversations.save(c);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it also help you

```
db.users.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
      "$nor": [{
          "gyms": {
              "$exists": false
          }
      }, {
          "gyms": {
              "$size": 0
          }
      }, {
          "gyms": {
              "$size": 1
          }
      }]
  }
 }, {
  "$unwind": "$gyms"
}]).pretty()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "x" : ["an array"] })
> db.test.insert({ "x" : { "type" : "object" } })
> db.test.find({ "x" : { "$type" : 3 } })
{ "x" : { "type" : "object" } }
```

Comment: The problem is that `$type: 3` evaluates to true for both objects and arrays containing objects. So if you added `{ "x" : [{ "type" : "object" }] }` it would not work